# "Cooking is a process used to make food" is that a passive sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

I have been wondering whether or not that is a passive sentence. My teacher said that "the tree called cacao tree" is not a passive sentence. The "a process" in "cooking is a process to make food" makes me question my answer. I believe it is a passive sentence, but i still have some doubts

Comment: Does cooking really _make_ food? It didn't make the apple I just ate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an active sentence.

The structure is [Subject] [active verb] [Complement [participle phrase]]

The active verb is "is" and the complement is "A process used to make food".

The participle phrase "used to make food"  has a past participle. This modifies "process" and "process" is the implied subject of this verb. It does have a passive sense: "Somebody uses a process -> A process is used (by somebody)"  But "used" is not the main verb of the sentence. We classify a clause based on the main verb, not on the presence of participle phrases.

So this is an active sentence.

"A tree called cacao tree" is not a sentence (at least not unless you mean "a tree contacted cacao tree on the telephone")  It is a noun modified by a past-participle phrase. There is no main verb.